# Установка KeepAlive опции для Windows сокетов

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi, сокет

C#:

```
    [DllImport("test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern void SetupKeepAliveOpt(IntPtr sock);

    static void ProcessIncomingConnection(Socket socket) {

        Console.WriteLine("Incoming connection!");

        while (true) {

            byte[] package = new byte[1024];
            socket.Receive(package);

            List<byte> packageList = new List<byte>(package);
            while (packageList.Count > 0 && packageList.Last() == 0) packageList.RemoveAt(packageList.Count - 1);
            package = packageList.ToArray();

            if (package.Length == 0) break;

            Console.WriteLine("\nReceived: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(package) + "\nSize: " + package.Length);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("End");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        string remoteIp = "192.168.1.2";
        Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.D1) {

            socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 19000));
            socket.Listen(10);

            while (true) ProcessIncomingConnection(socket.Accept());
        }
        else {

            socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(remoteIp), 19000));

            SetupKeepAliveOpt(socket.Handle);

            while(true) {

                Console.Write("Send: ");
                string data = Console.ReadLine();

                if (data.Length == 0) break;

                socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data));
            }
        }

        socket.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("CLOSED");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

C++ (dll):

```
// SetSockOpt.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "Ws2def.h"
#include "Winsock2.h"
#include "Mstcpip.h"
#include "iostream"

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

typedef void(*LPSOCKCLOSEPROC)(DWORD sock);

DWORD WINAPI ErrorWaiting(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    DWORD dw = WaitForSingleObject(*(HANDLE*)lpParameter, INFINITE);
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Event!", NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void SetupKeepAliveOpt(DWORD sock)
{
    SOCKET socket = (SOCKET)sock;
    struct tcp_keepalive tcpkeepalive;

    tcpkeepalive.onoff = TRUE;
    tcpkeepalive.keepalivetime = 200;
    tcpkeepalive.keepaliveinterval = 1000;

    //
    // Send socket IO code.
    //

    LPDWORD lpcbBytesReturned;
    INT nSize;

    WSAIoctl(socket,
        SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS,
        (LPVOID)&tcpkeepalive,
        sizeof(tcpkeepalive),
        NULL, 0,
        reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(&nSize),
        NULL, NULL);

    //
    // Setup socket close event.
    //

    HANDLE hEvent = OpenEvent(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, false, L"CloseEvent");
    WSAEventSelect(socket, hEvent, FD_CLOSE);

    DWORD dwThreadId;
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, ErrorWaiting, &hEvent, 0, &dwThreadId);
}
```

Данный код работает без ошибок, но уведомления в виде msgbox'а при отключении удалённого компьютера от сети я дождаться не могу (в течении заданной секунды, да и вообще никогда). Подскажите, в чём причина?

Comment: У Вас тут в коде `OpenEvent`, т.е. где-то до этого вызывается `CreateEvent`?

Comment: + я бы еще перехватил `FD_READ`: нулевой размер буфера тоже говорит о том, что противоположная сторона закрывает соединение.

Comment: @mega: Вы правы, заменил на `HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, L"CloseEvent");`. Теперь событие происходит сразу как только запускается поток... `WaitForSingleObject` возвращает разные значения каждый раз.

Comment: Для `WSA` вообще лучше использовать `WSACreateEvent` вместо `CreateEvent`. Хотя они конечно совместимы с обычными виндовыми событиями. Тут вроде флаг `ManualReset` должен быть `TRUE`, а не `FALSE`.

Comment: Теперь оно вообще не происходит. Может быть действительно надо `WSACreateEvent`?

Comment: А может быть управляющий код опцию не включает?

Comment: Нет. Сейчас просто закрыл настроенный сокет, а уведомление так и не пришло.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61777/discussion-between-mega-and-d-stark).

Answer (score 2):

Решение состоит в отказе от нативной прослойки в виде dll, т.к. всё достаточно хорошо реализуется средствами самого C# :)

`socket.SetSocketOption` результата не даст, т.к. KeepAlive опция *включена по-умолчанию*. Интервал между пробами составляет порядка 2 часов.
Чтобы понизить это смешно огромное время нужно настроить опцию. Причём на обеих сторонах соединения (желательно одинаково).

Настройка выполняется через `socket.IOControl`. Как сделать это есть ответ [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722240/instantly-detect-client-disconnection-from-server-socket). Так же могу предложить хорошую статью по этой теме (там же есть рабочий пример на C++): https://rsdn.org/article/net/keep_alive.xml

Теперь, когда после подключения опция настроена, мы можем спокойно работать. Если удалённая сторона внезапно отключится, мы по истечению заданного нами таймаута на попытках операций с сокетом (`Receive`, `Send`) будем получать исключения.

---

Я бы так же отметил, что лично заметил одну странность. Интервалы в keepalive структуре задаются в десятках мс или что-то около этого. Хотя везде пишут, что там просто миллисекунды. Имхо, но если в C#, где мы устанавливаем опцию через `socket.IOControl` написать keepaliveinterval = 500, то после того как удалённая система будет отключена от сети, исключение на моменте отправки будет начинать вылезать спустя минимум 4700 мс (а обычно 5000 +- 80-100 мс).

---

```
    static void SetKeepAliveOption(Socket socket) {

        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(new uint());
        byte[] optInValue = new byte[size * 3];

        BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)1).CopyTo(optInValue, 0);
        BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)20).CopyTo(optInValue, size);
        BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)500).CopyTo(optInValue, size * 2);

        socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.KeepAliveValues, optInValue, null);
    }
```